# Фильтрация массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

```js
var auto = [{
    marka: "BMW",
    model: "4k",
    cuzov: "A",
  },
  {
    marka: "Merc",
    model: "4k",
    cuzov: "B",
  },
  {
    marka: "Audi",
    model: "3k",
    cuzov: "C",
  },
  {
    marka: "Toyota",
    model: "1k",
    cuzov: "D",
  },
  {
    marka: "Lexus",
    model: "2k",
    cuzov: "E",
  },
  {
    marka: "Rang",
    model: "3k",
    cuzov: "F",
  },
  {
    marka: "BMW",
    model: "4k",
    cuzov: "G",
  },
  {
    marka: "BMW",
    model: "2k",
    cuzov: "Y",

  },
  {
    marka: "Audi",
    model: "3k",
    cuzov: "U",
  }
]
var marka = ["Audi", "Rang", "Merc"];
var model = ["4k", "2k", "3k"];
var rez1 = auto.filter(x => (marka.includes(x.marka) && model.includes(x.model) &&
  cuzov.includes(x.cuzov)));
console.log(rez1);
```

Фильтрую массив в соответствии с параметрами которые задал условно "Пользователь".
Такой вопрос. А что если "пользователь", скажем решит очистить массив `model`. Ну то есть выберет так, что должны показываться все модели. Тогда фильтр уже не будет работать. Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rez1 = auto.filter(x => (
  marka.includes(x.marka) && 
  (model.length == 0 || model.includes(x.model)) && 
  cuzov.includes(x.cuzov)
));
```

Если массив `model` "очищен", то есть пуст, его длина равна нулю. В этом случае `x.model` не играет роли, и проверка модели (вторая строчка в условиях) будет возвращать `true`.

Comment: А можно узнать что означает вот это model.length == 0?

Comment: @Sinevik https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: Я не совсем про это. Я не понимаю, model.length равно 0 или model.includes(x.model) вот это вот, как это влияет на фильтрацию

Comment: @Sinevik Добавил в ответ.